# Express console shows many requests

Tags: node.js, logging, express, get

I'm a little confused as to how each page load should work in express. Is this a normal log status writing all the static assets in the page or should it only show a the view requested?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you wanted to ignore logging requests for static files, but to continue logging routes and middleware defined after logger(), you would simply move static() above

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it later... It turns out i can get super confused if i don't sleep enough.. I accepted your answer...